# Passing data to child component using props not working in vue js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios

i've been learning vuejs for 2 weeks and i'm stuck a day to this problem when i passing a reactive data to child component using axios

here's the code :

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box-container">
      <TreeChart
        :json="tree"
        :class="{ landscape: landscape.length }"
        @click-item="clickItem"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import TreeChart from "@/components/TreeChart.vue";
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import http from "@/common-setup/http";

export default defineComponent({
  props: ["treeUid"],
  setup(props) {
    const landscape = ref([]);
    let tree = ref({} as any);
    const router = useRouter();

    if (
      props.treeUid === undefined ||
      props.treeUid === null ||
      props.treeUid === ""
    ) {
      router.push({ name: "NotFoundResource" });
    }

    let response = http
      .get(`/wv/tree/show/${props.treeUid}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.response.length === 0) {
          tree.value = {};
          router.push({ name: "emptyTree" });
        }

        tree.value = response.data.response[0];
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("done");
      });

    function clickItem(item: any) {
      console.log(item);
    }
    return { tree, landscape, clickItem };
  },

  components: {
    TreeChart,
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  @apply flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  @apply relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.box-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

here is setup api on child component

```
import { ref, watch, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";
import { TreeTypes } from "@/types/Tree";

export default function treeChart(props?: any) {
  let treeData = ref({} as any);
  const { ctx: _this }: any = getCurrentInstance();
  // console.log(props.json);

  watch(
    props.json,
    (props) => {
      let showKey = function (jsonData: any) {
        jsonData.extend = jsonData.extend === void 0 ? true : !!jsonData.extend;
        // console.log(jsonData);
        if (Array.isArray(jsonData.children)) {
          jsonData.children.forEach((c: any) => {
            showKey(c);
          });
        }
        return jsonData;
      };
      if (props) {
        treeData = showKey(props);
      }
    },
    { immediate: true }
  );

  function toggleTree(treeData: any): void {
    treeData.extend = !treeData.extend;
    _this.$forceUpdate();
  }

  return { treeData, toggleTree };
}
```

if i use dummy data not data from axios it will working and it become more weird when in hot reload mode, i tried to console it the data from axios suddenly appear.

is there something wrong how i pass the data with axios to the child component ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what errors you're encountering but I'd like to help; can you reproduce the issue by forking this project (https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gqhgwq?file=src%2FApp.vue) and sharing the link once you get it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sure i will try to reproduce it,